# If I have a .bib file, how do I make it so only specified fields are used in a reference without manually deleting each field in the file?

Tags: bibtex, formatting, citing

I am using Mendeley to manage references for a project I am working on. It does a wonderful job of filling out each field so that details such as the DOI, page numbers, authors etc are accounted for. The `.bib` file that I export has all of these details, and as a result many are included in the citation when I reference a work with `\cite{}`. I am aware that I can control the format of my bibliography by specifying the style in LaTeX and using these styles is preferred when it comes to publishing, but what I was wondering is if there was a way to specify the fields I want explicitly and only pull those for the reference without having to go into my `.bib` file and manually deleting fields I do not want like "url" or "annotations"? This is supposing I have a `.bib` file with hundreds of references and I would like to avoid going one-by-one deleting the useless info.

For example if I had a file `test.bib`:

```
@article{PleaseCiteMe2022,
abstract = {This is an abstract},
archivePrefix = {arXiv},
arxivId = {xxxx.xxxx},
author = {Original Poster},
doi = {xx.xx.xx.xxx.xxxx},
eprint = {xxxx.xxxx},
file = {location},
issn = {xxxxxxxx},
journal = {TeX Stack Exchange},
keywords = {Help,Me},
pages = {1},
title = {{This has a lot of info}},
volume = {12},
year = {2022}
}
```

and a document `test.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    I am citing \cite{PleaseCiteMe2022}.
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

But I only want to show the author, the arXivID, the journal, the DOI, and title, is there a way to specify this?

Comment: by default all fields are ignored, the bst file specified by `\bibliographystyle` needs to pull out just the ones you want.

Comment: Would this mean that I need to create a custom `.bst` for `\bibliographystyle` in order to grab the fields I wanted? Like if I did something like `\bibliographystyle{user_defined}`?

Comment: yes I suspect most off-the shelf bst styles are not going to ignore `year` for example (many will ignore the firs7t  or 8 fields in your example, but you want to show arXivID so probably need a custom bst file (someone will probably post one here...)

Comment: That's a reasonable answer. I'll look into that, thanks for the insight!